# underscore.js - shortest way to convert a list to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

What is the shortest way to convert a list (a `FileList` object, or another array-ish browser data structure) to an array using underscore?

Curretly I use this (in CoffeeScript):

```
files = _.map(fileList, (it)->it)
```

but I was wondering if there is a shorter way.

Comment: I guess this one: http://underscorejs.org/#toArray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortest way would be to use underscore's **[_.toArray(list)](http://underscorejs.org/#toArray)**  method:

> "Converts the list (anything that can be iterated over), into a real
>   Array. Useful for transmuting the arguments object."

Example:

```
(function(){ return _.toArray(arguments).slice(1); })(1, 2, 3, 4);
=> [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: what's wrong with `[].slice.call(fileList)`?